# Please also provide the deletion comment on the delete link in the post for moderators

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-delete

When you vote to delete in the review system, you are presented with a(n awesome) context menu to automatically leave a comment

[image: Context menu]

However, when you vote to delete (or delete directly if you're a mod) you are not presented with the menu, having to enter it manually or not at all.

[image: No context]

It'd be nice to have the context menu there too.